# JS actions after Ajax response in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

There is the following select tag for ajax request:

```
= form_for owner, url: change_status_admin_owner_path(owner), remote: true do |f|
  .row
    = f.select(:status_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Status.all, :id, :description, 
    owner[:status_id]), {}, { data: { remote: true, url: change_status_admin_owner_path(owner), method: :patch } })
```

Action in controller:

```
def change_status
    Owner.find(params[:id]).update!(status: Status.find(params[:owner])
end
```

And change_status.js.erb:

```
$("html").remove();
```

It's JS for example, not really task, but it doesn't work - instead of doing my JS code I get:

```
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='container'>
      $("html").remove();
    </div>
  </div>
```

I.e. Rails renders my JS code as just text! What's wrong in my code? Thanks!

Comment: why $('html').remove(); what are you trying to do?

Comment: It's example code! I use it to check JS is working

Comment: can  you give a simple alert(); and check

Comment: I did it - it was the same ..

Comment: @malcoauri use debugger or a simple alert message inside your change_status.js.erb file to check if it's even going there or you can simply check it in console. what do you want to acheive here? Can you write proper code may be there could be something wrong with js

Comment: can you show me the response from the log

Comment: Have you tried adding the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) block?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an action to set the response as JS, try adding a [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) block like this:

```
def change_status
    Owner.find(params[:id]).update!(status: Status.find(params[:owner])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

This will look for a `change_status.js.erb` file in your views folder.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment & `manu29.d`'s answer, you'll be best looking at using the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) block:

```
def change_status
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js #-> looks for change_status.js.erb
  end
end
```

--

However, this would not explain why your response is being rendered as HTML (and not JS)

I would surmise that since your application is not processing the response as the `text/javascript` [mime type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), Rails will be looking for *any* format of view called `change_status` in your folder (I.E it can be `.html.erb` or `.js.erb`)

As it's found one called `.js.erb`, I would guess that it's being processed as static HTML (as `erb` is just a preprocessor). To fix this, the `respond_to` block will basically set the mime-type, allowing your browser to digest the `JS`